# how to approach implementing TCO'ed recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, scheme, tail-call-optimization

I have been looking into recursion and TCO. It seems that TCO can make the code verbose and also impact the performance. e.g. I have implemented the code which takes in 7 digit phone number and gives back all possible permutation of words e.g. 464-7328 can be "GMGPDAS ... IMGREAT ... IOIRFCU" Here is the code.

```
/*Generate the alphabet table*/
  val alphabet = (for (ch <- 'a' to 'z') yield ch.toString).toList

/*Given the number, return the possible alphabet List of String(Instead of Char for convenience)*/
  def getChars(num : Int) : List[String] = {
      if (num > 1) return List[String](alphabet((num - 2) * 3), alphabet((num - 2) * 3 + 1), alphabet((num - 2) * 3 + 2))
      List[String](num.toString)
  }

/*Recursion without TCO*/
  def getTelWords(input : List[Int]) : List[String] = {
    if (input.length == 1) return getChars(input.head)
      getChars(input.head).foldLeft(List[String]()) {
        (l, ch) => getTelWords(input.tail).foldLeft(List[String]()) { (ll, x) => ch + x :: ll } ++ l
      }
  }
```

It is short and I don't have to spend too much time on this. However when I try to do that in tail call recursion to get it TCO'ed. I have to spend a considerable amount of time and The code become very verbose. I won't be posing the whole code to save space. [Here is a link to git repo link](https://gist.github.com/1387374). It is for sure that quite a lot of you can write better and concise tail recursive code than mine. I still believe that in general TCO is more verbose (e.g. Factorial and Fibonacci tail call recursion has extra parameter, accumulator.) Yet, TCO is needed to prevent the stack overflow. I would like to know how you would approach TCO and recursion. The Scheme implementation of Akermann with TCO in [this thread](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2673) epitomize my problem statement.

Comment: what does total cost of ownership have to do with recursion? ;)

Comment: There is no Haskell in the linked thread. The code you seem to be discussing is in scheme.

Comment: In fact, in Haskell, often but not always, tail-calls are not that important. Your problem above, for example, is really about producing a stream (i.e. a lazy list) of results. It can be written with standard list tools in Haskell very straightforwardly.

Comment: Why do you want to force the use of tail-call optimisation? Not all recursive routines should be tail-call recursive. If each recursive call has its own state, then either it won't be tail calls, or you'll have to maintain your own state and pass it around (which is what your implementation does). In either case, the space consuming behaviour is the same. If you really need to worry about stack overflow, just use the iterative version, there's no law against it.

Comment: @Kim Stebel, recursion has everything to do with total cost of ownership for the maintainer(owner), you know. you don't want to get it blown up(stack overflown) in your hand ;)

Comment: @sclv Thanks. Fix the error. I will look into lazy list, stream.

Comment: @Paul Well, I heard that the iterative is usually frown upon in the FP world, thus I am trying to get into the habit of recursion. Since I am getting into Scala, there is more restraint for me and would like to learn more about opinion and approach of how other tackle the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible that you're using the term "tail call optimization", when in fact you really either mean writing a function in iterative recursive style, or continuation passing style, so that all the recursive calls are tail calls?

Implementing TCO is the job of a language implementer; one paper that talks about how it can be done efficiently is the classic  [Lambda: the Ultimate GOTO](http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-443.pdf) paper.

Tail call optimization is something that your language's evaluator will do for you.  Your question, on the other hand, sounds like you are asking how to express functions in a particular style so that the program's shape allows your evaluator to perform tail call optimization.

Comment: dyoo, I am not sure if scheme and lisp compiler do the TCO for all your recursion or not. However, in Scala, the recursion has to be tail call so that it can get optimized by the compiler because Scala run on JVM and JVM does not natively support optimization for recursion. Here is the blog bit.ly/s9LQIF on Scala requirement for the recursion to be tail call. So, yes, my question is about approachable way to get "tail call recursion" over "recursion"

Answer (score 4):

As sclv mentioned in the comments, tail recursion is pointless for this example in Haskell. A simple implementation of your problem can be written succinctly and efficiently using the list monad.

```
import Data.Char
getChars n | n > 1     = [chr (ord 'a' + 3*(n-2)+i) | i <- [0..2]]
           | otherwise = ""
getTelNum = mapM getChars
```

Comment: How do i call the function? getTelNum 123 gives me a type error. Thanks.

Comment: Should be getTelNum [1, 2, 3]

Comment: @Chris: That's because the `1` digit doesn't correspond to any letters. Try `getTelNum [2, 3, 4]`, for example.

Comment: @hammar thanks. I just started getting into Scala a month ago only without any prior knowledge in FP before. It will take a bit of time for me to read your Haskell code and learn about list monad.

Answer (score 3):

As said by others, I would not be worried about tail call for this case, as it does not recurse very deeply (length of the input) compared to the size of the output. You should be out of memory (or patience) before you are out of stack

I would implement probably implement with something like

```
def getTelWords(input: List[Int]): List[String]  = input match {
   case Nil => List("")
   case x :: xs => {
      val heads = getChars(x)
      val tails = getTelWords(xs)
      for(c <- heads; cs <- tails) yield c + cs
   }
}
```

If you insist on a tail recursive one, that might be based on

```
def helper(reversedPrefixes: List[String], input: List[Int]): List[String] 
  = input match {
    case  Nil => reversedPrefixes.map(_.reverse)
    case (x :: xs) =>  helper(
      for(c <- getChars(x); rp <- reversedPrefixes) yield c + rp,
      xs)
  }
```

(the actual routine should call `helper(List(""), input)`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code has really slashed the execution time a lot and your tail call recursion is as concise as your standard recursion. Yet, your TCO version also trails performance compare to your standard recursion. Anyway, thanks again for the Scala(FP?) idiomatic way of expression.